# How to show div per table row if checkbox is ticked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out the best way to make the currently hidden divs of each line that is generated to only show if the box is ticked (these are 2nd party name, 2nd party surname and mobile number)

What I've tried:

I've tried initially having them split into seperate rows but I couldn't get that to work as trying to bind the box check to a unique ID is proving difficult because they are auto generated.

I've also tried

```
if ($('input.checkboxAC').prop('checked')) {
          removeAttr( 'hidetopline' );
```

(hidetopline is the name of the div but I'm trying to figure how to do that individually, i thought removing the style of display:none could work)

What I'm using: bootstrap, jquery

### Jquery

```
  function displayResult()
  {
      document.getElementById("tableAc").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" style="display:none"><i><br />2nd Party First Name<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div></td><td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" style="display:none"><i><br />2nd Party Surname<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div></td><td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" style="display:none"><i><br />Mobile<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div><td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox" style="width: 150px"/></td></td>';

  }
```

### HTML

```
<h2>COA Table</h2>
  <table class="table" id="tableAc">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="style2">Product Type</th>
        <th class="style2">NSC</th>
        <th class="style2">Account Number</th>
        <th class="style2">Joint A/c</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="acRow" class="first">
        <td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" ><i><br />2nd Party First Name<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div></td>
        <td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" ><i><br />2nd Party First Name<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div></td>
        <td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="text" style="width: 150px"/><div class="divhidden" ><i><br />2nd Party First Name<i/><br /><input type="text" style="width: 150px" /></div></td>
        <td class="style1" style="border-color: #FFFFFF"><input type="checkbox" style="width: 150px" class="checkboxAC"/></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
          <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Add A/c</button>            

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkboxfunction = function(){
    var $this = $(this); // this is the checkbox
    var $row = $this.closest("tr") //this is the row
    var $fields = $row.find(".divhidden") // these are the fields
    //if you can't add a class, just build a jQuery collection manually 
    //with the required fields

    //For debug purposes:
    //console.log("I've clicked the checkbox ", $this, " for the row: ", $row, " to ", $this.is(':checked')?"show":"hide", " these fields: ", $fields);

    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      $fields.show();
    }else{
      $fields.hide();
    }
}
```

the handler would ideally be bound like this:

```
$("#tableAc").on("click", "input.checkboxAC", checkboxfunction);
```

I binded the function to the container to not bind a function for EVERY checkbox. This also works with dinamically generated checkboxes inside the container.

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the confusion. I deleted the checkbox and remade it and forgot to call it checkboxAC. I'll edit it now and then give your solution a go. thanks

Comment: No problem, Add the checkbox class to the HTML snippet in your Question so it's clear for every other user :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've made the changes you kindly advised however I'm still getting issues. When I check the box the divs are not shown as they are meant to. I feel like I'm doing something obvious wrong but have looked at code to long to figure it out..

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed your part on the handler.

Comment: You shouldn't update your question with the solution I'm providing. I know it's well-intentioned (I used to do it myself), but if you do that, when the problem is solved, the answer and the question will look the same and it won't help anyone ;)

Comment: Sorry, yeah total newb thing to do. I'll see if I can change it back

Comment: No problem, that happens. Also, while you're a it, your tr reads: `id="acRow" class="first"`. Did you mean the other way around? Since you have multiple acRows, that ID doesn't make sense. Also, you probably don't need a ".first" class, you can use the [:nth-child css selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) :)

Comment: So yeah, I have the handler added in to load on (document).ready and added in the var checkboxfunction and put in var $this =$("checkboxAC") and did row.find(".divhidden"); but the checkbox is still not unhiding the divs. Do I need to make these individual containers?

Comment: updated the answer. Special atention to the new binding (to the table id). Uncomment the console.log line for testing.

Comment: I got it working, I looked over it again and made a few changes. thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help. If you needed to make any significant change to my answer to make it work, post it and I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried:

```
if ($('input.checkboxAC').prop('checked')) {
    removeAttr( 'hidetopline' );
```

You could try replace that with:

```
if ($('input.checkboxAC').prop('checked')) {
    $('#hidetopline')attr( 'display', 'block' );
} else {
    $('#hidetopline')attr( 'display', 'none' );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes that could work if I had the div there called "hidetopline" however as I am generating extra rows I need a tickbox beside each row that shows or hides fields in that row. I wonder if I used a jquery function to generate a unique id for each row, would that work?

Comment: That would definitely work yeah, just increment a number for each generated row and then loop through all of them and perform the function for each id + i.